# Python String to Bool conversion yields True for all cases

Tags: python, string, boolean

I have trying to achieve the following. I wrote code to or the values of a string and count the number of 1's in the string.

```
a='11001'
b='00111'

a and b
'00111'

a or b
11001
```

Can someone explain how this works. The answer that I am expecting is that when I do `a and b`, the result should be `00001` and when I do `a or b`, I should get `11111`, the logical `and` and `or`.

I do understand that non empty strings yield True for all cases. So I can explain the above behavior, thought I do not understand how to implement boolean `and` and `or`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because all non-empty strings are `True`. You are looking for bit wise operations which don't happen by magic. You will need to explicitly perform them.

Comment: By the way, to count the number of `1` in a string made of only 0 and 1s, you have a much simpler way: `sum(int(c) for c in "0001111")`

Comment: @Annapoornima The title for this question is wrong and misleading, please fix it. The question is about: Bitwise operations on strings representing binary numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a='11001'
b='00111'
c = ''
```

case "and":

```
for bit_1, bit_2 in zip(a, b):
    if bit_1 == bit_2:
        c += '1'
    else:
        c += '0'
```

case "or":

```
for bit_1, bit_2 in zip(a, b):
    if bit_1 == '1' or bit_2 == '1':
        c += '1'
    else:
        c += '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `and` keyword does not work like you expect. What it does is:

1. evaluate the left-hand operand.
2. if that operand is falsy (`None`, `False`, 0, empty string, …) then return it.
3. otherwise evaluate the right-hand operand and return it.

There, `'11001'` is not falsy, as it's a non-empty string so `'11101' and '00111'` returns the second string.

Maybe you wanted to do a bitwise operation, using the bitwise and operator, `&`?

```
>> 0b11001 & 0b00111
1
```

Answer (score 1):

`and` and `or` keywords work on Boolean values. A non-empty string is `True` in python.

If you want to perform bit operations, you can use something like this:

```
>>> a='11001'
>>> b='00111'
>>> bin(int(a, 2) & int(b, 2))
'0b1'
>>> bin(int(a, 2) | int(b, 2))
'0b11111'
```

And to count the number of 1's in the or result, you can use the `count()` function:

```
>>> bin(int(a, 2) | int(b, 2))[2:]
'11111'
>>> bin(int(a, 2) | int(b, 2))[2:].count('1')
5
```